# SPFX error: failed to load component dependency "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base'

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

Anyone else getting the above error? Two webparts that worked fine yesterday today are failing with:

> [SPWebPartErrorCode.ScriptLoadError]:: Unable to load web part
>   WebPart.DelmeWebPart.25d255cb-7c93-4eb6-ba2e-189e6703d0e8,Error:
>   ***Failed to load component "6b2c929f-6fae-498c-9109-a7ebb06ae045" (DelmeWebPart). Original error: ***Failed to load component dependency
>   "@microsoft/sp-webpart-base" from component
>   "6b2c929f-6fae-498c-9109-a7ebb06ae045" (DelmeWebPart). script
>   resources due to: undefined. CALLSTACK:: Error at t [as constructor]
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-01-30.032/sp-loader_en-us_2032158c7e81d8ca6cabd8d5f3651bfa.js:57:19057)
>   at new t
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-01-30.032/sp-webpart-base_en-us_83e865c7afcaf523daf607745ec20719.js:47:22053)
>   at Function.t.create
>   (https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-01-30.032/sp-webpart-base_en-us_83e865c7afcaf523daf607745ec20719.js:47:22502)
>   at
>   https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/sp-client-prod_2017-01-30.032/sp-webpart-base_en-us_83e865c7afcaf523daf607745ec20719.js:48:714

I even created a new webpart from the yeoman generator and it too  fails with the same error. This is only happening in the *_layouts/15/workbench.aspx* though-- some webparts I had previously deployed to my site are running fine. These are all react webparts.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get the error with new webpart create with yeoman using no framework

Comment: Ok, even my old webparts are now working. I did not change anything... must be the storm!

Answer (score 4):

That was our fault.  Sorry about that.  Rolled back the change a few hours ago.

Comment: its happening again after I upgraded to GA

Comment: Is there a chance that you have build using the 1.0 release, but your farm hasn't been upgraded yet?  If you look at the network traffic (dev dashboard), you'll want to make sure that the files (say sp-client-base) are coming from a CDN with 2017-02-17.xxx in the path.  If they say 2017-02-13.xxx, your farm hasn't been upgraded yet.

Comment: yes, i was in the wrong folder, was building an older version of code. it's working now